# Direction of resultant vector

Tags: vector

in this question- a motorboat is racing towards north at 25 km/hr and the water current in that region is 10 km/hr in a direction 60 degrees east of south. find the resultant velocity and direction of resultant velocity of the boat.
For getting the velocity i just used the cosin formula and got 22 km/hr approx but i cant seem to understand how to calculate the direction when the angle between the vectors is 120. it is easy when the angle is less that or equal to 90 when we just find tan theta where theta is the angle between the vectors. but how do we go about doing this?

Comment: please elaborate. i have made the diagram (parallelogram) but how should i go further.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity is as actually a vector with a direction. If you sketch this you will have a vector addition (build a parallelogram) of The boats speed vector and the water flows speed vector. The directions of the vectors you can extract from the given direction. For example take north as (1,0) direction and draw an arrow in the correct length (speed).

```
v_boat = 25 * (1,0)
v_flow = 10 * ...
v_sum = v_boat + v_flow
v_sum_magnitude = magnitude of v_sum
```

For the background:
Velocity is working with the principle of superposition.

Comment: oh alright i understand that method but i wanted it to be done without coordinate geometry and coordinates. it is meant to be done by plane vector algebra.